# Make divs right below each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so that if I copy and paste a div, the pasted div appears right under the one I copied. Here is my code:

```css
.friend {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="friend" href="#1">
  <div class="user-status" id="friend-status"></div>
  <img id="friend-profile-picture" src="images/talk/blank-profile-picture.png">
  <h5 id="friend-name">Jane Doe</h5>
</a>
<a class="friend" href="#2">
  <div class="user-status" id="friend-status"></div>
  <img id="friend-profile-picture" src="images/talk/blank-profile-picture.png">
  <h5 id="friend-name">Jane Doe</h5>
</a>
<a class="friend" href="#3">
  <div class="user-status" id="friend-status"></div>
  <img id="friend-profile-picture" src="images/talk/blank-profile-picture.png">
  <h5 id="friend-name">Jane Doe</h5>
</a>
```

This is what it looks like now:

[image: enter image dhere]

I am trying to make the spacing between the .friend divs smaller so that they are closer together vertically. They must have the same class.

Comment: you'll need to post some additional relevant css. also, and this doesn't address your actual question, but you are using `id` like it's a `class`. there should only be one unique `id` per page, and you have the same `id` for all three `div` tags, `img` tags and `h5` tags.

Comment: What is the issue here ?? You want them vertically aligned close to each other & they are.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I want them like 1px apart from each other vertically

Comment: @RussellC. check for my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to give say a "dynamic" `1px` gap between each `friend` element, then adding the below CSS will do

```
.friend:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

> This will add a bottom margin of 1px to all the `.friend` elements **except the last one**. So even if you copy pasta the element, the spacing will be automatically present.

Answer (score 0):

Try to inspect element and see which element have padding or margin. Most likely it caused by the H5 element.

Comment: None of the elements have a margin/padding that would affect this. I would just set the bottom to something appropriate however all the divs use 1 class and the bottom would increase for every div.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide more information such as the relevant CSS, screenshot of the inspect element etc. If possible paste your code to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so easier for people to help you.